# Transition background-image to grey

Tags: html, css, background-image, transition

Trying to make background-image smoothly fade out into transparent, with the text opacity unchanged, however I only managed a on/off transition. 
Transition with opacity does not work here, since I need the text to stay opaque. Any thoughts how this could be done?

Here's my code:

```css
.grid {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#one {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  background: url('https://doorcountypulse.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/1-PP-3-9-18-Raccoon-at-cracked-corn-660x440.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 40%;
}

#one:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), url('https://doorcountypulse.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/1-PP-3-9-18-Raccoon-at-cracked-corn-660x440.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 40%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="flexbox">
    <div id="one">
      <div id="textbox">
        I need this picture to smoothly fade into transparent (grey) and this text to stay opaque.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the :: after tag, which will help you do what you expect.

You must remember about content = "", without which the picture will not appear. 
Also remember to correctly set the z-index which is responsible for the location of the layer.

And here's the solution for your example:

```css
.grid {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#one {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

#one::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://doorcountypulse.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/1-PP-3-9-18-Raccoon-at-cracked-corn-660x440.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 40%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0.3s;
}

#textbox {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

#one:hover::after {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, visibility 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="flexbox">
    <div id="one">
      <div id="textbox">
        I need this picture to smoothly fade into transparent (grey) and this text to stay opaque.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! While your code does exactly what I asked to help with - smooth transition to gray on :hover - it would be be just best if it also added an ease-out backwards animation. Anyway you helped me a lot, tx!

Comment: @BI You are welcome. Look at it right now. Esse-out animation should work fine!